# ElevateZoom solo hace zoom la primer imagen Javascript y Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

Estoy intentando que funcione correctamente el efecto lupa en una tienda creada en prestashop, pero solo logro hacer que funcione en la primero imagen mostrada. Cuando se selecciona otra imagen y te pones con el ratón encima se visualiza con zoom la imagen de portada, siempre.

No logro soluciona este problema. A ver si alguien es capaz de decirme cual prodria ser la solución. Adjunto a tema una imagen de lo que sucede y el código empleado.

Efecto que produce:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Código del tpl:

```
<div class="images-container">
  {block name='product_cover'}
    <div class="product-cover">
      <img id="{$product.id}" class="js-qv-product-cover" src="{$product.cover.bySize.large_default.url}" alt="{$product.cover.legend}" title="{$product.cover.legend}" style="width:100%;" itemprop="image">
      <div class="layer hidden-sm-down" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal">
        <i class="material-icons zoom-in">&#xE8FF;</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  {/block}

  {block name='product_images'}
    <div class="js-qv-mask mask">
      <ul class="product-images js-qv-product-images">
        {foreach from=$product.images item=image}
          <li class="thumb-container">
            <img
              class="thumb js-thumb {if $image.id_image == $product.cover.id_image} selected {/if}"
              data-image-medium-src="{$image.bySize.medium_default.url}"
              data-image-large-src="{$image.bySize.large_default.url}"
              src="{$image.bySize.home_default.url}"
              alt="{$image.legend}"
              title="{$image.legend}"
              width="100"
              itemprop="image"
            >
          </li>
        {/foreach}
      </ul>
    </div>
  {/block}
</div>
{hook h='displayAfterProductThumbs'}
```

Código del js:

```
$('.product-cover').find('.js-qv-product-cover').each(function () {
        $(this).elevateZoom({
            zoomType: "lens",
            lensShape: "round",
            lensSize: 200
        }
        );
    });

    $(".thumb-container").click(function(){
        console.log("Click en la minuatura");
        $('.product-cover').find('.js-qv-product-cover').each(function () {
            $(this).elevateZoom({
                zoomType: "lens",
                lensShape: "round",
                lensSize: 200
            }
            );
        });
    });
```